# List replacements

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

Sorry, for the broad title, didn't know how to best describe it. I have a list likes this:

```
list = {{{1, 2, 3, {4, 5, 6}}, {1, 2, 3, {4, 5, 6}}}, {{1, 2, 
    3, {4, 5, 6}}, {1, 2, 3, {4, 5, 6}}}}
```

And I want to replace the second part of the list elements, i.e. {4,5,6} everywhere by just the first element of this part, i.e. 4. the list should then look like this:

```
list2 = {{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}, {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}}
```

I can do it with some complicated constructions looping through all the list elements by means of `Table` but there must be an easier way by using `Replace` or `MapAt`and I just can't figure it out.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
list2 = Replace[list, {a_, ___} -> a, {3}]
list2 = MapAt[First, list, {All, All, -1}]
```

> {{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}, {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}}

If `list` is very big I think the fastest one would be

```
Join[Drop[list, None, None, -1], list[[All, All, {-1}, 1]], 3]
```

Comment: Thanks Coolwater! Can you maybe comment on the first line that uses `Replace` a bit, I don't understand what exactly you did there ;). Especially this part `{a_, ___}->a`

Comment: In the deepest level `{3}` we need to replace elements with the form `{__}` (i.e. a list with one or more elements). I write instead `{a_, ___}` (one element plus zero or more elements) to keep a reference only to what's needed

Comment: Ah I see, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Also:

```
ClearAll[f1, f2, f3, ☺]
f1 = ReplacePart[#, {_, _, -1, 0} :> (# &)] &;
f2 = Module[{l = #}, l[[All, All, -1, 0]] = # &; l] &;
f3 = Module[{l = #}, l[[All, All, -1]] = l[[All, All, -1, 1]]; l] &;
☺ = # & @@@ {##} & @@@ # & /@ # &;   (* for fun *)

f1 @ list
```

> {{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}, {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}}

```
Equal @@ (#@list & /@ {f1, f2, f3, ☺})
```

> True

Comment: So many solutions, thanks :)!

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
```

With another similar entry added at level 1 as an example:

```
list = {{{1, 2, 3, {4, 5, 6}}, {1, 2, 3, {4, 5, 6}}}, {{1, 2, 
    3, {4, 5, 6}}, {1, 2, 3, {4, 5, 6}}}, {1, 2, 3, {4, 5, 6}}}

Replace[list, {x__Integer, k : {y__}} :> {x, First@k}, -1]
```

or:

```
list /. {x__Integer, k : {y__}} :> {x, First@k}
```

> {{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}, {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}, {1, 2, 3,
> 4}}

Answer (score 2):

Using `Map` and `AtomQ`:

```
Map[If[AtomQ[#], #, ##[[1]]] &, list, {3}]

(*{{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}, {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}}*)
```